# how can i destroy publisher stream from the opentok session?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, opentok

I am using tokbox in my web project, here I got an issue like I want to end the call from session but after reconnecting the call chat signal is sending double time from my view.Can any please give me rly ...

```
  **if (publisher)
                {
                    publisher.destroy();
                    $rootScope.isCallRunning = 0;
                    session.unpublish(publisher);
                    publisher=null;  
                    session.disconnect();                    

                }
```

above code is using before ending the call**

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. You need to explain more about how the call is initialised and also confirm that this destruction code is actually being used. Also please explain what you mean by 'after reconnecting'. Is this a button on the UI which ends the call and starts it again? It would be useful to know what OpenTok API gets called in response to that button.